# Hibernate and Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Hibernate, Spring MVC in one of the jsp screen having same input text fields like field name is MILESTONE1, MILESTONE2, MILESTONE3,-----MILESTONE10. The screen has a plus symbol and minus symbol for adding and removing columns but the db table has ten columns, after clicking the submit button the table shows null values for all of the 10 columns.

So I have used the code like this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#removeVariable").hide();
    var counter = 2;

    $("#addVariable").click(function() {
        $("#removeVariable").show();
        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 milestones allow");
            return false;
        }

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(
             document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'milestoneDiv' + counter);
             newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                                '<div class="row">'
                                + '<div class="col-md-12">'
                                + '<p class="bx-form"><label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MileStone '
                                + counter
                                + '  </label>'
                                + '&nbsp;'
                                + '<input type="text" size="32" class="mileStone1[]" placeholder="Please Enter Milestone" name="mileStone1' 
                                + counter
                                + '" id="mileStone1'
                                + counter
                                + '" value="" ></p></div></div>');

            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#mileStoneGroup");
            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeVariable").click(function() {
            counter--;

            $("#milestoneDiv" + counter).remove();
            if (counter == 2) {
                $("#removeVariable").hide();
                alert("No more milestones to remove");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**Entity Class**

```
package com.bwits.clinedge.ctms.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name="CONTRACT_DETAILS")
public class ContractDetails implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CONTRACT_DETAILS_ID", nullable=false)
    private int contractDetailsId;

    @Column(name="TRKID", nullable=false)
    private String trackId;

    @Column(name="INVID", nullable=false)
    private String piId;

    @Column(name="INVNAM",nullable=false)
    private String piName;

    @Column(name="STUDYID", nullable=false)
    private String studyId;

    @Column(name="STUDYNAM", nullable=false)
    private String studyName;

    @Column(name="CONTYP", nullable=false)
    private String contractType;

    @Column(name="CONSTDTC",nullable=false)
    private Date contractStartDate;

    @Column(name="CONENDTC", nullable=false)
    private Date contractEndDate;

    @Column(name="CONPAY", nullable=true)
    private String paymentTerms;

    @Transient
    private String mileStone1[];

    @Column(name="CONOTH",nullable=true)
    private String contractOthers;

    @Column(name="CONIRBPY",nullable=true)
    private String irbPayment;

    @Column(name="CONIECPY",nullable=true)
    private String iecPayment;

    @Column(name="CONMODPY",nullable=true)
    private String modeOfPayment;

    @Column(name="CONINFPY",nullable=true)
    private String inFavorOf;

    @Column(name="CONPYAT",nullable=true)
    private String paybleAt;

    @Column(name="CONPYPAN",nullable=true)
    private String panNumber;

    public int getContractDetailsId() {
        return contractDetailsId;
    }

    public void setContractDetailsId(int contractDetailsId) {
        this.contractDetailsId = contractDetailsId;
    }

    public String getPiId() {
        return piId;
    }

    public void setPiId(String piId) {
        this.piId = piId;
    }

    public String getStudyId() {
        return studyId;
    }

    public void setStudyId(String studyId) {
        this.studyId = studyId;
    }

    public String getPiName() {
        return piName;
    }

    public void setPiName(String piName) {
        this.piName = piName;
    }

    public String getStudyName() {
        return studyName;
    }

    public void setStudyName(String studyName) {
        this.studyName = studyName;
    }

    public String getContractType() {
        return contractType;
    }

    public void setContractType(String contractType) {
        this.contractType = contractType;
    }

    public Date getContractStartDate() {
        return contractStartDate;
    }

    public void setContractStartDate(Date contractStartDate) {
        this.contractStartDate = contractStartDate;
    }

    public Date getContractEndDate() {
        return contractEndDate;
    }

    public void setContractEndDate(Date contractEndDate) {
        this.contractEndDate = contractEndDate;
    }

    public String getPaymentTerms() {
        return paymentTerms;
    }

    public void setPaymentTerms(String paymentTerms) {
        this.paymentTerms = paymentTerms;
    }

    public String[] getMileStone1() {
        return mileStone1;
    }

    public void setMileStone1(String[] mileStone1) {
        this.mileStone1 = mileStone1;
    }

    public String getContractOthers() {
        return contractOthers;
    }

    public void setContractOthers(String contractOthers) {
        this.contractOthers = contractOthers;
    }

    public String getTrackId() {
        return trackId;
    }

    public void setTrackId(String trackId) {
        this.trackId = trackId;
    }

    public String getIrbPayment() {
        return irbPayment;
    }

    public void setIrbPayment(String irbPayment) {
        this.irbPayment = irbPayment;
    }

    public String getIecPayment() {
        return iecPayment;
    }

    public void setIecPayment(String iecPayment) {
        this.iecPayment = iecPayment;
    }

    public String getModeOfPayment() {
        return modeOfPayment;
    }

    public void setModeOfPayment(String modeOfPayment) {
        this.modeOfPayment = modeOfPayment;
    }

    public String getInFavorOf() {
        return inFavorOf;
    }

    public void setInFavorOf(String inFavorOf) {
        this.inFavorOf = inFavorOf;
    }
    public String getPaybleAt() {
        return paybleAt;
    }

    public void setPaybleAt(String paybleAt) {
        this.paybleAt = paybleAt;
    }

    public String getPanNumber() {
        return panNumber;
    }

    public void setPanNumber(String panNumber) {
        this.panNumber = panNumber;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
}
```